# How to identify a derived class and launch its member from the base class through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, derived-class, base-class

I have a base class:

```
abstract class ClassPlugin
{   
    public ClassPlugin(eGuiType _guyType)
    {
        GuiType = _guyType;
    }

    public eGuiType GuiType;
}
```

then I have various derived classes, one of them being this

```
class ClassIO : ClassPlugin
{
    public ClassIO(eGuiType _guyType, eIoType _ioType) : base(_guyType)
    {
        GuyType = _guyType;
        ioType = _ioType;
    }

    eIoType ioType; 
    public enum eIoType { UKNOWN, READ, WRITE, MONITOR }
    public override void Action(){...}
}
```

so now when launching my application I use that code:

```
public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>()
{
    return FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)));
}

public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly assembly)
{
    var derivedType = typeof(T);
    return assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t =>
                    t != derivedType && derivedType.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();

}
```

finally I use it with

```
var output = FindAllDerivedTypes<ClassPlugin>();
foreach (var classType in output)
{
    if (classType.Name == "ClassIO")
    {
        foreach (var item in classType.GetMembers())
        {
            ????        
        }
    }
}
```

so what I need to do is [pseudocode to be put where the ??? are]

```
bool IsMonitorType = false;
if(item.member == eIoType && item.Value == eIoType.MONITOR)
{
    IsMonitorType == true;
    break;
}
```

and then

```
if(item.member.Name "Action")
{
    item.member.execute();
}
```

so in short I have to:

1. identify the instance type throgh eIoType
2. if ioType == MONITOR execute its Action routine

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
if (classType.Name == "ClassIO")
{
    //You can get the field like this
    var fieldInfo = classType.GetField("ioType",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (fieldInfo != null)
    {
        //...
    }

    //You can get the method like this
    var methodInfo = classType.GetMethod("Action");
    if (methodInfo != null)
    {
        //create an instance of ClassIO
        var classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new eGuiType(), ClassIO.eIoType.MONITOR);
        //Execute Action method
        methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you think you're going to check the value of eIoType though, you're just dealing with the **Type** `ClassIO` here not an instance of it

Comment: Thanks for helping but I still don't know how to get the eIoType ioType value. I tried var aaa = fieldInfo.GetValue(); but it's not correct.

Comment: What are you expecting to get the value of? You don't have an instance of ClassIO, you are just dealing with the **Type** ClassIO

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. I have defined all the instances among which var cio = new ClassIO(eGuiType.COMMON_PERMANENT_TAB,  eIoType.READ); and so on....

Comment: if you have the `FieldInfo` object in the code in my answer and an instance you can get the value like this: `var io = (ClassIO.eIoType)fieldInfo.GetValue(cio)`. That will attempt to get the field value from your ClassIO instance

Comment: That would work I know but I need to access it thorugh reflection. In short, after having defined all child instances I need to check if each of them is ClassIo and if ioType=XXX and in that case launch Action()

Comment: That is getting it through reflection. You can't do what you're trying to do which is getting a value from a type. Without the instance you have no value to retrieve.

Comment: But I have the instances! I am iterating after having defined all of them

Comment: Your code above `FindAllDerivedTypes<T>()` does not go off and magically connect to instances you've created of your derived types just because you've declared them before this bit of code. All your code is doing if find Types derived from the Type `ClassPlugin`